# Accessing the esri js api over ssl

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I changed the url i was using to fetch the esri js api to https://js.arcgis.com/3.7 and i can see in Fiddler that the call to that url is going out as ssl. But the file it pulls down (init.js) must be firing off other calls to fetch more components of the api and those are only going over http.
Short of hosting the api myself is there a way to fetch the whole enchilada over ssl?

Comment: Since you mentioned fiddler I'm guessing you're using IE? Can you post code that reproduces what you're seeing? We've had bugs in the past where we mistakenly loaded resources over http but those should all be fixed at 3.7.

Comment: yeah, this is an ie app. unfortunately it is behind a firewall and i can't expose it live. It may be that my issue is related to something else. Is it possible to use an ssl-secured proxy page that then calls a non-ssl page inside of the network to then return results out? I'm not sure if i'm explaining that very well.

Comment: If you could isolate the code causing the problem and post it we could get to a definite conclusion. As long as you access your proxy over https, it doesn't matter what the proxy is on the server.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is the JSAPI is not detecting ssl as you document protocol? This may also be a problem specific to running your page through Fiddler.

From the developer help at https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jshelp/intro_accessapi.html

"Run the application using https, this is necessary because the API uses the document protocol to determine whether the ArcGIS API for JavaScript should make http or https requests after the page loads."